# SharePoint SPFx App uploaded in App Catalog but not appearing in "app store" page

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx, spfx-webparts

I have created a SharePoint SPFx web part called "No Framework", and uploaded it to the app catalog but it is not appearing in the app store. Please advise what the issue is.

SPFx Package details:

[image]

Getting below error:
[image]

Comment: Are there any errors against uploaded package in app catalog? is it enabled properly in app catalog?

Comment: Hi, i am getting this error "Couldn't add this app.Check your network connection and try again."